manager.monitorCharacteristicForDevice is not working for reading the notify value using nordic semiconductor bluetooth device
I am unable to read value from my nordic bluetooth device . I tried printing the characteristic value and below is the output
{ "_manager": { /* Manager information */ },
"deviceID": "My_Device_ID", "id": 9, "isIndicatable": false,
"isNotifiable": true, "isNotifying": false,
"isReadable": false, "isWritableWithResponse": false,
"isWritableWithoutResponse": false, "serviceID": 7,
"serviceUUID": "XXXX0001-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXX",
"uuid": "XXXX0003-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXX", "value": null }
Below is my code, to read notifiable value---
manager
.connectToDevice('My_Device_ID')
.then(device => {
console.log('Connected to device:', device.id);
// Monitor the characteristic for notifications
manager.monitorCharacteristicForDevice(
'D4:CB:F7:11:5E:C6',
'XXXX0001-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXX',
'XXXX0003-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXX',
(error, characteristic) => {
if (error instanceof BleError) {
console.error(
'Error monitoring characteristic:',
JSON.stringify(error),
);
return;
}

// Handle notifications received from the characteristic
console.log('Received notification:', characteristic.value);
},
);

Please help as I am unable to read the data from bluetooth device

Which device are you using to run this code on?
What are your build system and libraries?

Thanks for replying
Sigurd Hellesvik. I am using nrf microcontroller. I have resolved the issue by using below code.
char[1].monitor((err, update) => {
if (err) {
console.log(
characteristic error in handleReadWithCharMonitor: ${err},
);
console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
} else {
console.log(
'*handleReadWithCharMonitor data is:',
decode(update.value),
); }  }); where char array has 2 json values with 2 different characteristic uuids
